# ng-change not called we ng-model update in promise.then

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise

I am having a problem with ng-change in a select not being called when I update the ng-model parameter in my promise.then.  My select is:

```
<select ng-model="currentReport"
    ng-options="rpt.ReportDisp for rpt in availableReports" 
    ng-change="updateDependent()"></select>
```

availableReports is an array of these objects and is retrieved by a $http call in my service. When the call finishes I want to make sure the 1st entry is selected and do the code:

```
webServices.getReports(user, menu1, menu2)
            .then(function (result) {
                $scope.availableReports = result.data.d;
                $scope.currentReport = $scope.availableReports[0];
             }
```

This sets the select to the 1st report, but the ng-change does not call the function updateDependent().

Also, I tried adding a call to the updateDependent() function into the .then as shown below.  but when the function is called $scope.currentReport is undefined.

```
webServices.getReports(user, menu1, menu2)
            .then(function (result) {
                $scope.availableReports = result.data.d;
                $scope.currentReport = $scope.availableReports[0];
                updateDependent();
             }
```

Anyone know what is going on?

**Found the issue, me**

The function update updateDependent is declared as $scope.updateDependent().  So I need to change the reference in http associated .then to $scope.updateDependent().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure about the rules on when ng-change is fired off when updated from the controller, but in regards to your other issue.

I would modify updateDependent to take in a parameter like so:

```
<select ng-model="currentReport"
    ng-options="rpt.ReportDisp for rpt in availableReports" 
    ng-change="updateDependent(currentReport)"></select>
```

and in your back-end

```
webServices.getReports(user, menu1, menu2)
        .then(function (result) {
            $scope.availableReports = result.data.d;
            $scope.currentReport = $scope.availableReports[0];
            updateDependent($scope.currentReport);
         }
```

I find it better to be more explicit about what the function is doing by passing in the parameter for readability. Also, it simplifies the testing story of updateDependent.

Comment: Thanks.   That is a good suggest.  I tried it before to see if it would fix the original issues with $scope.currentReport, but it had no effect.  Still I like the idea of being more explicit.

Comment: Thank you. Have you confirmed that $scope.currentReport is being populated correctly?

Comment: Brocco,Thanks for pointing me in taking another look at the .then code.  I found the issue.  The problem is that "scope".  I should have referenced $scope.updateDependent() instead of updateDependent().

Comment: That'll do it too, you weren't showing that code (not that I would have caught it)